# replace data in random data from 10, 100 with size(4,10)

Tags: pandas, numpy

I made random data from 10, 100 with size(4,10). How can I take replace a `number <50` with its square root

this is the code I tried

`df=df.apply(lambda x:np.sqrt if x<50) df`

Comment: You should add the code that you used to create this small sample of random data, then you'll almost certainly get help

Comment: try this? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-replace-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-that-satisfy-a-condition-in-python

Comment: I added some benchmarks to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions needs to be applied to a column so for loop through them.

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x) if x<50 else x)
```

Comment: This is a good solution but it's not the fastest.

Comment: That is fair. I just wanted to show the solution that was closest to Amaldev's mindset. With a df of this size it really does not matter. Hopefully some insight into lambda function is also gained. Yes, for larger dataframes this would not be advised.

Comment: Yes I perfectly understand it. And I upvoted it cos it solves the problem. I'm going to add a  benchmark to my answer.

Comment: `df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.sqrt(x) if x < 50 else x)` would be my recommendation if trying solve this as close to OP as possible.

Comment: @HenryEcker I added some benchmarks to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataFrame.mask` to selectively change the values that are < 50.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
np.random.seed(410112)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, (4, 10)))

df = df.mask(df.lt(50), np.sqrt(df))
```

---

```
print(df)
           0          1          2          3          4          5          6          7         8   9
0  72.000000   5.744563   4.795832  63.000000   6.782330   4.898979  93.000000  83.000000  82.00000  71
1  69.000000  99.000000  65.000000   6.633250   6.480741  82.000000   6.082763   3.162278  72.00000  70
2   3.872983  75.000000  51.000000  65.000000  91.000000  69.000000  72.000000  97.000000  69.00000  85
3  80.000000  54.000000  95.000000   6.403124  66.000000  85.000000   6.164414   4.795832   6.63325  86
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to ALollz's solution, which it appears to me to be the fastest, is using `np.where`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
np.random.seed(410112)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, (4, 10)))

df[df.columns] = np.where(
    df.values<50,
    np.sqrt(df.values),
    df.values)
```

## Benchmark

### Data Small example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(410112)
df_bk = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, 100, (4, 10)))
```

### Data Bigger example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(410112)
df_bk = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, 100, (100_000, 10)))
```

### Code

For all the 4 solutions I used

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
df = df_bk.copy()
# solution
```

### Results

[image]
[image]